# My master page has empty space on the bottom and right side. Can I "center" my master page and set a background image?

Tags: asp.net, css, page-layout

Here's how it looks like right now:

[my screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x3qpJ.jpg)

Is there a way for me to center the area that has content, and place a repeating background image so the site doesn't look so empty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Centering horizontally can be accomplished by wrapping the content you wish to center in a div, and applying the style:

```
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
```

to said div.

This will take care of your issue of space on the right. You can place a background image (repeating or not) using CSS as well.

Your larger issue will be the vertical centering. As far as I'm aware, there's (currently) no easy, cross-browser (including IE6/7) way of accomplishing that. I'd like to be proven wrong here by another user, though. :)

Comment: For vertical centering I've had to resort to tables. I die a little inside every time I do it.

Comment: That sounds good. :) Can I wrap my master page with a <div> tag though? :S

Comment: You can wrap that portion in a div tag, or the Content Area. You could wrap the entire thing in a div tag by having the opening div tag just beneath <body> and the closing div tag right above </body>.

Comment: @Jon: Yup, been there, done that. Same dirty feeling. I also have the same problem trying to make equally-sized columns. (Which *really* shouldn't be as difficult as it actually is ... )

Answer (score 0):

<del>It looks to me like you just need some padding on the top and left in your content area.</del>

Sorry I didn't realize your page was only a portion of the screen.

Why not splice your site into parts (divs) and use a fluid layout?  [Here is an article](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/06/02/fixed-vs-fluid-vs-elastic-layout-whats-the-right-one-for-you/) from Smashing Magazine about Fixed vs Fluid layouts.

Comment: Not enough time. I have to hand in this project in 1 hour. :P Can I wrap my master page inside of a <div> tag?